# Granular routing with iptables and iproute2 over VPN

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, iproute2

On a host at my house I have a host for a VPN that I need for a couple of purposes. Living temporarily in Japan, it functions as a NAT for some devices so I can still use my NETFLIX and some other services. However I want that server to still use the normal net for downloads/web browsing. Currently, the following is a barebones copy of my configuration:

ip rule show

```
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 10
32767:  from all lookup main
32768:  from all lookup default
```

ip route show table 10

```
default dev ppp0 scope link
```

iptables-save

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [11:822]
:INPUT ACCEPT [11:822]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:872]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8:872]
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.102 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2831:752380]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [107531:7116617]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [107652:7124121]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [41463962:7467495526]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

I would like to state that my actual iptables configuration is more elaborate, to include a couple of log statements for new connections of the FORWARD side of the house and to avoid too many logs there is a blanket accept for ESTABLISHED,RELATED connections before the log statement and more ip addresses on the mangle table.
This configuration serves it's purpose for my devices, however I just attempted ssh'ing into it from a remote and can not. The reason is obvious, the replies from my ssh service are getting routed out eth0 instead of ppp0. Which brings me to my question.

It is possible to have fwmark 1 applied to all sessions originated over ppp0? I know, through some digging, that conntrack can perform matches based on the source ip of the session's originating host, but can I do something similar for originating dev?

The overall goal being that ssh can be performed from over the private subnet, my original ip address (japanese ip 204.xxx.xxx.xxx) or the vpn's ip (23.xxx.xxx.xxx) without constantly changing the configuration. An inelegant solution which would only allow ssh over the private and the VPN would be applying fwmark to any subnet other than the 192.168.xxx.xxx with sport being 22 in the mangle table, however that wouldn't allow for ssh over the japanese ip.

Answer (score 1):

Use CONNMARK to mark the connections:

```
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -i ppp+ -j CONNMARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 0x1 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```